# R: Avoid accidently overwriting variables

Tags: r, namespaces, overwrite

Is there any way to define a variable in R in your namespace, such that it can't be overwritten (maybe ala a "Final" declaration)?  Something like the following psuedocode:

```
> xvar <- 10
> xvar
[1] 10
xvar <- 6
> "Error, cannot overwrite this variable unless you remove its finality attribute"
```

Motivation: When running R scripts multiple times, it's sometimes too easy to inadvertently overwrite variables.

Comment: best practice in functional languages is to avoid global variables as much as possible. Use functions, changes made inside won't affect your global environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out `? lockBinding`:

```
a <- 2
a
## [1] 2
lockBinding('a', .GlobalEnv)
a <- 3
## Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'a'
```

And its complement, `unlockBinding`:

```
unlockBinding('a', .GlobalEnv)
a <- 3
a
## [1] 3
```

Comment: Just beware of possible side-effects. (like accidentally unlock-bind-ing something that shouldn't ever be unlocked)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Seems like good advice, but do you have an example?

Comment: If I could find it, I would :-( . Joran discussed this a week or two ago on another SO question.  OTOH, it's not in the R-Inferno, so maybe I'm being overly cautious.

Comment: ist there a way to automatically lockbind all variables that are created? and only unlockbind if needed?

Answer (score 7):

You can make variables constant using the `pryr` package.

```
install_github("pryr")
library(pryr)

xvar %<c-% 10
xvar
## [1] 10
xvar <- 6
## Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'xvar'
```

The `%<c-%` operator is a convenience wrapper for `assign` + `lockBinding`.

---

Like Baptiste said in the comments: if you are having problems with this, it's a possible sign of poor coding style.  Bundling the majority of your logic into functions will reduce variable name clashes.

Comment: There is a danger in using `%<c-%` together with operations like `x %<c-% 1 + 2`, it does not behave like `x <- 1+2`, meaning you need more brackets with `%<c-%`. In my opinion, if one uses final variables, it would be good to declare them by hand with `lockBinding()`.